# Filter dataset on either value OR nothing

Tags: reporting-services, filter, dataset

I have a dataset that contains a lot of records. I would like to include all those records where PType in @Ptype OR PType = ''

```
YEARMONTH --|-- PTYPE --|-- VALUE
201207 --|-- bike --|-- 600
201208 --|-- moped --|-- 0
201209 --|-- '' --|-- 0
201210 --|-- bike --|-- 600
201211 --|-- '' --|-- 0
201212 --|-- car--|-- 1200
```

This is filtered using a parameter. The filtering occurs in the report on the reference to the shared dataset;

```
Expression:PType
Operator: in 
Value: @Ptype
```

Now when @PType contains ('bike','moped')

**I get this resultset:**

```
YEARMONTH --|-- PTYPE --|-- VALUE
201207 --|-- bike --|-- 600
201208 --|-- moped --|-- 0
201210 --|-- bike --|-- 600
```

**but I would like**

```
YEARMONTH --|-- PTYPE --|-- VALUE
201207 --|-- bike --|-- 600
201208 --|-- moped --|-- 0
201209 --|-- '' --|-- 0
201210 --|-- bike --|-- 600
201211 --|-- '' --|-- 0
```

So I would also like to see those records where Ptype is Empty/NULL/Nothing.
Is this possible?

If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the filter expression to be something like:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!PTYPE.Value)
      or Fields!PTYPE.Value = ""
      or InStr(Join(Parameters!PType.Value, ","), Fields!PTYPE.Value) > 0
    , true
    , false)
```

Set this as a boolean filter to show when the expression `= true`.

This will check if the field exists in the multi-value parameter, but will also include `NULL` values and empty string values.

Works OK for me:

[image]